# How to determine the runtime for the two reverse string methods in O() notaion?

Tags: c#, big-o

I have two queries to reverse a string. Need to compare them:

```
public string ReverseD(string text)
{
    return new string(text.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
}

public string ReverseB(string text)
{
    char[] charArray = text.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```

How can I determine the run time for these two algorithms in O() notation? Need to compare.

Answer (score 3):

Both are O(n) - they both go through the full array, which is O(n).

The first algorithm has worse *constant factor* though since effectively you are "buffering" the full array and then emit it in reverse order (unless `Enumerable.Reverse()` is optimized for arrays under the hood, don't have Reflector handy right now). Since you are buffering the full array, then emit a new array in reverse order you could say that effort is 2*N, so the constant factor c = 2.

The second algorithm will use array indexes so you are performing n/2 element swaps within the same array - still O(n) but a constant factor c = 0.5.

Comment: How do we determine this O() notation? Is there any step by step tutorial to find the runtime? Actually I was asked this in an interview. There were bunch of C# codes and they wanted me to find run time in O() notation.

Comment: I tested the performance of the Reverse extension method vs Array.Reverse recently and discovered that Array.Reverse is faster on large strings. Of course, we're talking 3 vs 7 milliseconds on a string consisting of about 100k worth of text, so I don't think it's a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

While knowing the asymptotic performance of these two approaches to reversing a string is useful, it's probably not what you really need. You're probably not going to be applying the algorithm to strings whose length becomes larger and larger.

In cases like this, it's actualy more helpful to just run both algorithms a bunch of times, and see which one takes less time.

Most likely it will be the straight `Array.Reverse()` version, since it will intelligently swap items within the array, whereas the `Enumerable.Reverse()` method will `yield return` each element in reverse order. Either will be O(n), since they both manipulate each of the n items in the array a constant number of times.

But again, the best way to see which one will perform better is to actually run them and see.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. when you say run and see... does it mean log the start and end time in code? But as I mentioned to Broken Glass that I was asked to determine runtime in O() notation. Is there a link with examples to determine it for c# codes?